# Linux network programming:getaddrinfo() get wrong result

Tags: c, linux, sockets, getaddrinfo

This is a simple program, I write it to find out all of a domain's `A record`.

I complie it and get no errors nor warnings.

Then I run it, I only found it give wrong IP, such as:

**./a.out www.google.com**

`2.0.0.0`

`2.0.0.0`

This is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <netdb.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    struct addrinfo addrC;
    struct addrinfo *addrL;
    struct addrinfo *temp;

    memset(&addrC, 0, sizeof(addrC));
    addrC.ai_family = AF_INET;
    addrC.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;
    addrC.ai_protocol = IPPROTO_TCP;

    if (getaddrinfo(argv[1], "http", &addrC, &addrL) != 0)
    {
        perror("getaddrinfo!");
        exit(1);
    }

    for (temp = addrL; temp != NULL; temp = temp->ai_next)
    {
        char addrBuf[BUFSIZ];
        void *addrCount = &((struct sockaddr_in*)temp)->sin_addr;
        inet_ntop(temp->ai_addr->sa_family, addrCount, addrBuf, sizeof(addrBuf));
        printf("%s\n", addrBuf);
    }
    for (temp = addrL; temp != NULL; temp = addrL)
    {
        addrL = temp->ai_next;
        free(temp);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Why? and how to correct it?

Comment: `struct addrinfo` is not `struct sockaddr_in` and casting between them is likely to produce garbage. You can try to use `temp->ai_addr` instead, which is a `sockadr_in`. (Why do you name the result `addrCount` is beyond me, it is meant to be an address, not a count of anything).

Answer (score 1):

You have an error in your pointer casting inside the loop, it should be:

```
void *addrCount = &((struct sockaddr_in*)temp->ai_addr)->sin_addr;
```

Otherwise you are reading garbage and passing that garbage to `inet_ntop`, so you get garbage as a result :)

Answer (score 1):

The other answer is correct, but I'd recommend to use `getnameinfo` (using NI_NUMERICHOST) instead of `inet_ntop`. Then you wouldn't have had this error in the first place.

Also, you're not supposed to loop and free the result from `getaddrinfo`. You call `freeaddrinfo` to free the whole array.